# wordpress pexeto grid gallery cutom links are not chaging on click its changing on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using pexeto wordpress theme in that I want change images links to `www.domain.com/cutomposttypecatgeory/postname`. It's changing once I click on it due to links are added through ajax. If I refresh it then it's working fine for me. Kindly help how to fix it.

```
register_post_type( PEXETO_PORTFOLIO_POST_TYPE,
              $arr=array( 'labels' => $labels,
                 'public' => true,
                 'show_ui' => true,
                 'capability_type' => 'post',
                 'hierarchical' => false,
                 'rewrite' => array('slug'=>$cname),
                 'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category'),
                 'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'page-attributes') ) );
```

I want links should be change on click immediately.I also used `flush_rewrite_rules();` but still not working.

I was already tried it and my links are working fine except immediately changing it due to ajax links. Everything is done only links issues is there. ajax shows: "www.domain.com/portfolio/postname" as an link and if I refresh the page changed link is display  "www.domain.com/category/postname". I want it should be display while ajax response and It should be redirect it.

Comment: How to fix that ajax links changing issues ?

Comment: I think to disable ajax call it is solution for it. How to disable ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to make your portfolio custom post type permalinks contain a category name - if so, the WordPress *register_post_type()* function doesn't include an option to do this, so that would require quite a lot of additional coding.

In this case I would recommend using a plugin that can allow you build custom permalink structures for your custom post types, for example you can try the Custom Post Type Permalinks:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

it should give you the option to build this particular permalink structure.

Comment: Its already tried. Please look my question carefully and share exactly answer....!